# How to extract time for local time zone

Tags: salesforce, apex-code

Hi All
I want to extract time for my local time zone which i have set in my personal information

like  consider apex code below:

DateTime cDT = system.Now();
String localDateTime = cDT.format();

now localDateTime will be like 4/1/2011 4:22 PM

I want to extract 4:22 PM out of this

One method given in salesforce documentation is hour,minute methods. But this method takes datetime as argument. But our format method returnes a string.

The solution may be convert the string returned by format method to datetime type.
But could not. i tried parse method. it converted my local time back to GMT Time. Secondly i tried valueOf Method. But it accepts string in a specific format.

Please help me solving this problem. I have tries from my side. searched on net. but got no solution

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have got help from some other community and posting the answer for help of coders

**To extract Time :**
DateTime cDT = system.Now();
String localTime = cDT.format('h:mm a');

**Similarly Date can be Extracted :**
DateTime cDT = system.Now();
String localDate = cDT.format('d-MM-yyyy ');

Enjoy :)